# Pytest on Python Tools for visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, unit-testing, pytest, ptvs

Can debug python tests which are using pytest library on visual studio 2010 ? I added the -m pytest on the Interpreter arguments but the breakpoints are not hit, I can only run the test script without debugging it.

Answer (score 6):

Pytest recommends creating a standalone startup script.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pytest
    pytest.main()
```

This is what I do and PTVS debugging works for me.

Answer (score 5):

It would be great if you can be more specific. When I used pytools I found it very useful and found great help at http://pytools.codeplex.com. You can check http://pytools.codeplex.com/discussions.

Also check [Can I debug with python debugger when using py.test somehow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678792/can-i-debug-with-python-debugger-when-using-py-test-somehow) or [Python Unit Testing: Automatically Running the Debugger when a test fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398967/python-unit-testing-automatically-running-the-debugger-when-a-test-fails) for help as they have asked something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer fscore.I need to debug pytest tests using python tools for visual studio and not python debugger(pdb). On visual studio, on project properties->debug->interpreter arguments I added "-m pytest" so the test script will be run as "python.exe -m pytest test_scripts.py". I added the breakpoints on the test script, I run it using "start with debugging" but the breakpoints are not hit, the test is just run without debug.

Comment: Re: The codeplex links. "This site, including the discussions and issues, are no longer actively monitored.". They've gone to Github, sadly.