# Run pytest in PDB with pipenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pytest, pdb, pipenv

I saw this question: [Can I debug with python debugger when using py.test somehow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678792/can-i-debug-with-python-debugger-when-using-py-test-somehow) but it doesn't really help, because I need to debug hooks, some of them not written by me, where modifying the code of the hook is really cumbersome.

Also, `pytest` runs through `pipenv run`.  It's already difficult to make them both work together.  I couldn't so far find a combination of `pdb`, `pipenv` and `pytest` that would launch each other.

---

Another way I could do it is by calling `pytest.main()` from my code, however, this means that other people who want to run my tests will have to use this "trampoline" to run other tests.  I can live with this, but it still feels like it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: what is `pipenv exec`? not mentioned in its doc.

Comment: @georgexsh sorry, that's `pipenv run`, confused with some similar tool, maybe `bundler` or some such. I'll fix the question.

Comment: why can't you use breakpoints in pdb?

Comment: @georgexsh Because I'd need to get root, edit files in `/usr/lib/pythonX/site-packages`? Or, even worse, trying to discover where `pipenv` installed `pytest` and its plugins... That's just too much trouble for development process.

Comment: but you could control test case file, right? launch pdb within the test case,  set a breakpoint at the line in the hook you interested, then continue, pdb will break later.

Comment: @georgexsh wel... that's too late of course. In my more specific case, I wanted to see how some plugin parsed / added command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need, invoke pdb as early as possible:

```
`pipenv --py` -c 'import pdb, pytest; pdb.set_trace(); pytest.main()'
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to try this Sunday.

Comment: Sorry, I ended up adding a `__main__.py` file which fixed it for a time being, but then I ran into a host of problems with `pipenv` on Windows... at the moment, I'm not sure I'm going to use `pipenv` at all.