# Using sys settrace with pytest in python

Tags: python, pytest, trace

I want to trace the functions called and their return values for a test in python. I am using pytest module to call the test and sys.settrace for tracing the functions. However, this doesn't work and no functions are traced when I use pytest. It works when I use a locally defined function.

```py
filename="../tests/models/reading_comprehension/naqanet_test.py::NumericallyAugmentedQaNetTest::test_model_can_train_save_and_load"
sys.settrace(trace_calls_and_returns)
sys.gettrace()
pytest.cmdline.main(filename.split(" "))
```

This is what I get:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-5.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1
plugins: flaky-3.6.1, cov-2.8.1
collected 1 item

.../tests/models/reading_comprehension/naqanet_test.py .            [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 5.43s ===============================
```

Is there a way to use trace with pytest? Or some other way to handle it? I would like to handle this programmatically.

=============EDIT 1 ===============

Minimum reproducible example:

mytest.py

```py
from unittest import TestCase


class MyTest(TestCase):
    def testMe(self):
        a=5
        b=6
        k=self.m(5,6)

    def m(self, a, b):
        return max(a,b)
```

tracetest.py

```py
import sys
import pytest


def trace_calls(frame, event, arg):
    if event != 'call':
        return
    co = frame.f_code
    func_name = co.co_name
    caller = frame.f_back
    caller_line_no = caller.f_lineno if caller is not None else None
    caller_filename = caller.f_code.co_filename if caller is not None else None
    print('Call to %s on line %s of %s from line %s of %s' % \
        (func_name, func_line_no, func_filename,
         caller_line_no, caller_filename))
    return


sys.settrace(trace_calls)

pytest.main(["mytest.py"])
```

The output does not have the function "m" in "mytest.py"

=================== EDIT 2 ===================

Found the solution:

Just need to add this option to pytest:

```py
pytest.main(["--capture=no", "mytest.py"])
```

Thats it! :)

I got the hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418597/2435117)

Comment: Can't reproduce, tracing works (although I used [`pytest.main`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-main) instead of `pytest.cmdline.main` compat stuff, but it shouldn't be any different). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I see `cov-2.8.1` in your output. I'm pretty sure `pytest-cov` uses its own trace function that's overriding yours.

Comment: (Well, it's Coverage.py's trace function, really.) Anyway, see if turning that off helps.

Comment: nopes, that didnt help @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: Oh. You had output capture turned on.